# Trying to dynamically change height map created from image sequence using bpy

Tags: python, texturing, scripting

I got quite far creating a plane and loading the image into the displacement modifier to create the heightmap. The problem is I thought I could keyframe different images but I got an error saying the property "image" on the texture was not animatable.

Is there any way I can animate a change to the texture using bpy?

The alternative is I create an object for every single texture and then hide and unhide them but that sounds very ugly to me....any suggestions would be deeply appreciated!

I have added my code below:

```
# setting up the displacement plane
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(size=2, enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location=(0, 0, 0), scale=(1, 1, 1))
bpy.context.active_object.name = 'DisplacePlane'
bpy.ops.object.shade_smooth()
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
bpy.ops.mesh.subdivide(number_cuts=300)
bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='DISPLACE')
plane = bpy.data.objects['DisplacePlane']

# load some images for the displacement texture
bpy.data.images.load("//..\\..\\Downloads\\masked\\img0001.png", check_existing=True)
bpy.data.images.load("//..\\..\\Downloads\\masked\\img0002.png", check_existing=True)
bpy.data.images.load("//..\\..\\Downloads\\masked\\img0003.png", check_existing=True)

if not "DisplaceTexture" in bpy.data.textures.keys():
    bpy.data.textures.new("DisplaceTexture", type='IMAGE')

tex = bpy.data.textures["DisplaceTexture"]    
tex.image = bpy.data.images['img0001.png']
plane.modifiers["Displace"].strength = 0.2
plane.modifiers["Displace"].texture = tex

tex.keyframe_insert("image", frame=1)
tex.image = bpy.data.images['img0002.png']
tex.keyframe_insert("image", frame=1)
tex.image = bpy.data.images['img0003.png']
tex.keyframe_insert("image", frame=20)
```

Comment: which property are you trying to animate? the syntax is `keyframe_insert(data_path=data_path, frame=frame)` and you can get the <data_path> by right clicking the property you want to animate and select *Copy Data Path*

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I didn't realise that! I think the simplest would be to change the filepath so I tried the following:  tex.keyframe_insert(data_path=filepath, frame=1)
bpy.data.images["img0001.png"].filepath = "//..\\..\\Downloads\\masked\\img0002.png"
tex.keyframe_insert(data_path=filepath, frame=10) but it didn't work.....

Comment: oh no no, you're misunderstanding *Data Path*. Data Path is *path to the property to key*. Every field (number field, string field, etc) in blender's user interface has a **Data Path** which you can obtain by right clicking any field (say a number field) in the user interface of blender and selecting **Copy Data Path**. Say you wanted to animate a cube's *Rotation*, for that you would need the Data Path of cube's rotation and in order to get that, you can right click the cube's *Rotation* in the *Object Properties* which is *rotation_euler*.

Comment: That's why I asked which property you wanted to animate in the image so we can get the *Data Path* to that property. But it looks like you are trying to animate or shape shift animate from one image to another? Maybe you need to add *Shape Keys*

Comment: I ended up just creating 600 objects and then using hide_render. Thanks Harry for the help and for explaining how to use datapath. I finally get it!